# Angular - how to initialize default value on select2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I use select2 in my Angular project , Actually I have a problem that is I have no idea about how to set default value for select-option. Here is my code :

**HTML :**

```
<select-tag-manager parent-id="2" value="restaurant.type" ></select-tag-manager>
```

**Angular :**

```
app.directive('selectTagManager', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            parentId: '@',
            value: '='
        },
        controller: function($rootScope, $scope, Gateway, toaster, $element,  Tags) {
            var element;

            $scope.update = function () {

            };

            var makeStandardValue = function(value) {
                var result = [];
                angular.forEach(value , function(tag , key) {
                    if(result.indexOf(tag.tagId) < 0) {
                        result.push(tag.tagId);
                    }
                });
                return result;


            };

            var init = function () {

                Gateway.get('', '/tag?' + 'parentId=' + $scope.parentId, function(response) {
                    $scope.allPossibleTags = response.data.result.tags;
                });

                element = $($element).children().find('select').select2();
                console.log(element);

            };

            $scope.$watch('value', function(newval) {
                if( newval ) {
                    $scope.standardValue = [];

                    angular.forEach(newval, function(val, key) {

                        $scope.standardValue.push(val.tagName);

                    });
                    console.log($scope.standardValue);
                }
            });



            init();
        },
        templateUrl: 'selectTagManager.html'
    }
});
```

**selectTagManager.html:**

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            {{ standardValue }}
            <select class="select2" multiple="multiple" ng-model="standardValue" ng-change="update()">
                <option ng-if="tag.tagId" ng-repeat="tag in allPossibleTags" data-id="{{tag.tagId}}" value="{{tag.tagId}}">{{ tag.tagName }}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I got value

```
console.log($scope.standardValue);
```

result:    ["lazzania", "pizza", "kebab"]

But I don't know how to set them as default value in select-option. Any suggestion?

**EDITED :** 
I've just edited my question using [Angular-ui/ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2). I changed my template :

```
    <select ui-select2 = "{ allowClear : true }" ng-model="standardValue" multiple="multiple" >
        <option value="standardId" ></option>
        <option ng-repeat="tag in allPossibleTags" value="{{tag.tagId}}">{{tag.tagName}}</option>
    </select>
```

And also my js:

```
        $scope.$watch('value', function(newval) {
            if( newval ) {
                $scope.standardValue = [];
                $scope.standardId = [];
                // $scope.standardValue = makeStandardValue(newval);
                console.log('----------------------------------------------------------------------');

                angular.forEach(newval, function(val, key) {

                    $scope.standardValue.push(val.tagName);
                    $scope.standardId.push(val.tagId);

                });
                console.log($scope.standardValue);
                console.log($scope.standardId);
            }
        });
```

Nevertheless , Still I can't set default value.

Comment: What does `allPossibleTags` look like?

Comment: @spongessuck It's object that contains tagId , tagName.

Comment: You should try to migrate to [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) as ui-select2 is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

as demonstarted at http://select2.github.io/examples.html#programmatic, one can set default values for multiple select2 element as follows:

```
$exampleMulti.val(["CA", "AL"]).trigger("change");
```

so, in you case you have already element variable pointing to your select2:

```
element.val($scope.standardValue).trigger('change');
```

note, that this is jQuery approach of setting/changing values, angular approach would be to update values via ng model and its life cycle events

Comment: I use element.val($scope.standardValue).trigger('change'); and I get an error : Error: $rootScope:inprog
Action Already In Progress

Answer (score 0):

The IDs in your model need to match the IDs in your data source, so if your model is:

```
 ["lazzania", "pizza", "kebab"]
```

Then `allPossibleTags` needs to look like:

```
[{ tagId: "lazzania", tagName: "Lazzania" }, { tagId: "pizza" ...
```

Check out this plunk for a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/e4kJgrc69u6d3y2CbECp?p=preview